# Symfony2 - delete https for a dedicated route

Tags: symfony, https

I'm facing with a problem with a widget iframe which does not support https.
With Symfony2, is there a way not use https just for a dedicated route ?

Thanks

Comment: Beware, maybe your browser config does not let you get a http frame in your https page for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify this in your routing config file (e.g. `app/config/routing.yml`).

Example:

```
iframe_page:
    path: /somepath/iframe_page
    schemes: [http]
```

More info on this can be found here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/scheme.html